# Creating an AWS S3 Client to be used within Lambda

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Normally, when I want to create an S3 client for an application that is running on my local machine, I do something like this:

```
val client = new AmazonS3EncryptionClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY), encryptionMaterials)
```

When I run within Lambda though, I expect I shouldn't need the credentials part because that's handled by the role Lambda assumes. How do I do that?

Comment: Are you asking `client = new AmazonS3EncryptionClient( /* what goes here? */, encryptionMaterials)`?

Comment: @michael-sqlbot yes, exactly.

Comment: @dunedan - I didn't know what to try, and with the headache of loading into JARs into Lambda wanted to make sure I was going in the right direction.

Comment: Actually, it seems like https://stackoverflow.com/a/34773730/3830413 answers my question. I missed it because I was looking for a client with Encryption, but the same logic would apply without encryption I assume.

Answer (score 0):

In your Lambda console, there is a panel where you can set the IAM role used by your Lambda function.

[image: execution role]

You can then configure that role and attach policies to it by going to your IAM Management Console.

Comment: this doesn't help me unfortunately. I already know how to set this role. What I don't understand is what to pass the client when initializing it in the code. What Michael asked in the comment to the question is exactly what I'm missing.